# Image not closing correctly?

Tags: python, django, django-models, python-imaging-library

I am overwriting my save model function to resize profile pictures before saving them. My function looks like this:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Profile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    if self.avatar:
        with Image.open(self.avatar) as image:
            image_path = self.avatar.path
            image_name = self.avatar.path[:-4]
            image_ext = self.avatar.path[-4:]
            resize_images(image, image_path, image_name, image_ext)
            image.close()
```

My `resize_images` function looks like this:

```
def resize_images(image, image_path, image_name, image_ext):
    image = image.resize((400, 400), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    image.save(image_path, optimize=True, quality=95)

    medium_image = image.resize((250, 250), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    image.close()

    medium_path = image_name + "_medium" + image_ext
    medium_image.save(medium_path, optimize=True, quality=95)

    small_image = medium_image.resize((100, 100), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    small_path = image_name + "_small" + image_ext
    small_image.save(small_path, optimize=True, quality=95)
    medium_image.close()

    mini_image = small_image.resize((50, 50), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    mini_path = image_name + "_mini" + image_ext
    mini_image.save(mini_path, optimize=True, quality=95)

    small_image.close()
    mini_image.close()
```

When I save an image, it works perfectly, however, when I try to upload another image just a few seconds later, I get this error:

> PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file
>   because it is being used by another process:
>   'C:\Users\xx\xx\xx\media\users\179\avatars
>   \179312.jpg'

The culprit of this is the `resize_images` function because when I comment that out, this error goes away after reuploading every few seconds. However, I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I'm closing the images, but why is it still complaining?

**EDIT**
Seems like the true culprit whenever I'm saving the image in the `resize_images` function.

I also have this storage function as well:

```
avatar  = models.ImageField(storage=OverwriteStorage(), upload_to=create_user_image_path, validators=[validate_avatar],
                           default="default/avatars/default.jpg")

class OverwriteStorage(FileSystemStorage):

    def get_available_name(self, name, *args, **kwargs):

        try:
            file_path = os.path.dirname(name)
            shutil.rmtree(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, file_path))
        except FileNotFoundError:
            pass

        return name
```

Comment: try assigning `None` as the value of the variable which is used for the file upload, after the file has been uploaded.

Comment: @VasuDeo.S which variable exactly?

Comment: The one you used for upload

Comment: The image variable?

Comment: As a side remark: it's better to use splitext to get the filename and extension: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext